Unable to create node based on SOP_Star example in Houdini HDK
I've followed the SOP_Star example from the Houdini toolkit to create my custom node. The CMake compilation process is successful, but the node is not visible within the SOP menu in Houdini.
My Environment:
CMake version: 3.29.2
Compiler: gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Houdini version: 20.0.724
I'm encountering challenges while attempting to create a node based on the SOP_Star example from the Houdini toolkit. The issue seems to be specific to my Windows 11 environment, as I've successfully compiled and created the node using the SOP_Star example on my Ubuntu system.
CMakeLists.txt
type cmake
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.6)

project( HDK_Project )



list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/hfs20.0.724/toolkit/cmake/")


find_package( Houdini REQUIRED)

set( library_name SOP_NULLTEST)

houdini_generate_proto_headers( FILES SOP_NULLTEST.C )

add_library(
    ${library_name} SHARED
    SOP_NULLTEST.C
    SOP_NULLTEST.h
)


target_link_libraries( ${library_name} Houdini )

target_include_directories(${library_name} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})


houdini_configure_target( ${library_name} )

SOP_NULLTEST.C
type C++

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2024
 *  Side Effects Software Inc.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use of Houdini Development Kit samples in source and
 * binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the
 * following conditions are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. The name of Side Effects Software may not be used to endorse or
 *    promote products derived from this software without specific prior
 *    written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY SIDE EFFECTS SOFTWARE `AS IS' AND ANY EXPRESS
 * OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN
 * NO EVENT SHALL SIDE EFFECTS SOFTWARE BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA,
 * OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
 * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * The Star SOP
 */

#include "SOP_NULLTEST.h"

// This is an automatically generated header file based on theDsFile, below,
// to provide SOP_StarParms, an easy way to access parameter values from
// SOP_StarVerb::cook with the correct type.
#include "SOP_NULLTEST.proto.h"

#include <GU/GU_Detail.h>
#include <OP/OP_Operator.h>
#include <OP/OP_OperatorTable.h>
#include <PRM/PRM_Include.h>
#include <PRM/PRM_TemplateBuilder.h>
#include <UT/UT_DSOVersion.h>
#include <UT/UT_Interrupt.h>
#include <UT/UT_StringHolder.h>
#include <SYS/SYS_Math.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace UT::Literal;
using namespace HDK_TEST;

//
// Help is stored in a "wiki" style text file.  This text file should be copied
// to $HOUDINI_PATH/help/nodes/sop/star.txt
//
// See the sample_install.sh file for an example.
//

/// This is the internal name of the SOP type.
/// It isn't allowed to be the same as any other SOP's type name.
const UT_StringHolder SOP_NullTest::theSOPTypeName("hdk_nulltest"_sh);

/// newSopOperator is the hook that Houdini grabs from this dll
/// and invokes to register the SOP.  In this case, we add ourselves
/// to the specified operator table.
void
newSopOperator(OP_OperatorTable *table)
{
    table->addOperator(
        new OP_Operator(
            SOP_NullTest::theSOPTypeName,
            "TestSOP",
            SOP_NullTest::MyConstructor,
            SOP_NullTest::buildTemplates(),
            0,
            0,
            nullptr,
            OP_FLAG_GENERATOR));
}


/// This is a multi-line raw string specifying the parameter interface
/// for this SOP.
static const char *theDsFile = R"THEDSFILE(
{
    name        parameters
    parm {
        name    "divs"      // Internal parameter name
        label   "Divisions" // Descriptive parameter name for user interface
        type    integer
        default { "5" }     // Default for this parameter on new nodes
        range   { 2! 50 }   // The value is prevented from going below 2 at all.
                            // The UI slider goes up to 50, but the value can go higher.
        export  all         // This makes the parameter show up in the toolbox
                            // above the viewport when it's in the node's state.
    }
    parm {
        name    "rad"
        label   "Radius"
        type    vector2
        size    2           // 2 components in a vector2
        default { "1" "0.3" } // Outside and inside radius defaults
    }
    parm {
        name    "nradius"
        label   "Allow Negative Radius"
        type    toggle
        default { "0" }
    }
    parm {
        name    "t"
        label   "Center"
        type    vector
        size    3           // 3 components in a vector
        default { "0" "0" "0" }
    }
    parm {
        name    "orient"
        label   "Orientation"
        type    ordinal
        default { "0" }     // Default to first entry in menu, "xy"
        menu    {
            "xy"    "XY Plane"
            "yz"    "YZ Plane"
            "zx"    "ZX Plane"
        }
    }
}
)THEDSFILE";


PRM_Template*
SOP_NullTest::buildTemplates()
{
    static PRM_TemplateBuilder templ("SOP_NULLTEST.C"_sh, theDsFile);
    return templ.templates();
}

SOP_NULLTEST.h
type C++
#ifndef __SOP_NULLTEST_h__
#define __SOP_NULLTEST_h__


#include <iostream>
#include <SOP/SOP_Node.h>
#include <UT/UT_StringHolder.h>

namespace HDK_TEST
{
class SOP_NullTest : public SOP_Node
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    static PRM_Template *buildTemplates();
    static OP_Node *MyConstructor(OP_Network *net, const char *name, OP_Operator *op)
    {
        return new SOP_NullTest(net, name, op);
    }
    static const UT_StringHolder theSOPTypeName;

    const SOP_NodeVerb *cookVerb() const override;

protected:
    SOP_NullTest(OP_Network *net, const char *name, OP_Operator *op)
        : SOP_Node(net, name, op)
        {
            mySopFlags.setManagesDataIDs(true);
        }
    ~SOP_NullTest() override {};

    OP_ERROR cookMySop(OP_Context &context) override
    {
        return error();
    }

};
}

#endif

build Code
cmake -S . -B build
cd build
make
